# Inspecting large JSON data in Chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

There is a page on my website that uses jquery AJAX to request JSON data from the PHP backend. I want to view the JSON returned to the browser, and is trying to do so using Chrome browser's Developer tools, under `Network> Response`.

**Problem:** Although I am able to view the JSON data by selecting the XHR item there, the response appears to be cut off midway. According to Chrome, this JSON response is 300-400KB in size. I wonder whether if the webpage is receiving the full JSON response without truncation, and if not, how can I view the full data being received?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Have you tried the "preview" tab - it lets you view your result as a proper JavaScript object, with the ability to expand nodes.  It's much easier to work with than the raw text from the response tab.

[image]

Comment: For some reason, this "Preview" tab doesn't interpret the response as JSON and just displays it in all-black, one-line, plain text. The response `Content-Type` is `application/json`, but there's no color highlighting, formatting or expandable tree to bee seen anywhere. Any idea why?

Comment: @asbjornu It was working for me all along, but all of a sudden it doesn't do the highlighting/nesting anymore for JSON in the Preview tab. Did you find out how to fix that?

Comment: @Nathan, Chrome is still treating `application/json` as `text/plain` for me. No idea why.

Answer (score 7):

I using this extensions for Json viewer :- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc

Answer (score 5):

To see the complete response:

1. Navigate to Developer Tools > Network > the given response > Response tab.
2. Right click (control-click on Mac) in the Response area > Save As

[image: Response > Save As]

> Screenshot from Version 24.0.1312.57 on Mac.

Comment: that's exactly what I need but I don't have a Save As menu item there.

Comment: @GaryB96, I added a screenshot and the version I'm using to my answer.

Comment: Matt thanks for the follow up. I see the Save As... menu item only on "documents" in the _Network_ tab. If I switch to _XHR_, and right-click the Response tab on one of them, I see only _Open Link_ and _Copy_ Link. (Version 24.0.1312.57 m on Win7)

Comment: @GaryB96, I also don't have a Save As menu item on the Response tab for the XHR requests I spot checked. I recall it must have been there when I originally wrote this answer. In the examples I looked at just now, the response data wasn't truncated, so I could just Select All and Copy. Are you seeing examples where the response data is truncated?

Comment: It's not truncated per se but it does not word wrap and goes off the screen to the right.  I can hold down the mouse and select by dragging forever to the right but if I slip I wind up deselected :(  There must be a better way.

Comment: How about Ctrl-A to select all?

Answer (score 4):

I'm a little late to the party here but if you are at a breakpoint you can type the object name in and press "Enter" and the JSON object will be printed to the console window.

Comment: That's generally what I do and I think it's the best solution mentioned.