# ASP.NET JSON WCF Service Truncating Responses

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, wcf, json

I'm having a problem with my web service, sometimes it decides to randomly truncate data that is being sent.  I have no idea why.  In this example below, you see it just cut off the response.  In the next example, executed right after with the same query just a smaller amount of data.  In other cases, it's able to still load the same payload as the one that cancelled.  It's very strange.  I'm using Google Chrome and we have some responses in other functions that return 200-300kb of JSON data.

[image]
[image: Non-Truncated JSON Response from WCF]
The web.config is set to allow the max amount of data to be serialized and sent over JSON and the web service.

Anybody have any ideas?  I'll be happy to divulge more if it will help.  Thanks!

Comment: is that resolve your issue ............

Comment: Whwn you say allow max amount of data, dou you mean maxItemsInObjectGraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're experiencing the same issue reported (and resolved) here: [Inspecting large JSON data in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298165/inspecting-large-json-data-in-chrome)